Passing Headers/Parameters to React Native Web App
This is a newbie question I know, but how can I get the headers and parameters in React Native Web Application
So if the header contains for example Authorization Token I get it inside the RN App
Update Explanations
Let's assume I have an app called ClientApp, the client app use WebView with Authorization Bearer Token in it's GET request, when the ClientApp launch the WebView to access, for example my website app MyWebApp.com, I want MyWebApp.com which uses RNWeb to be able to extract the html header or url parameters to login the user automatically.

See the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#headers.

Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve that requires you to do the above?
